# Serve multiple directories with Apache

Tags: apache

I am running Apache on Ubuntu.  My /var/www folder consists of two directories

```
/codeigniter
/wordpress
```

I would like mydomain.com to point to /codeigniter and mydomain.com/blog to point to /wordpress.  I have acheived the first one but not the second.

I have the following in site-available/mydomain.com

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin me@example.com
  ServerName  www.mydomain.com
  ServerAlias mydomain.com

  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  DocumentRoot /var/www/codeigniter/public

  <Directory "/var/www/codeigniter/public">
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This works and when I go to mydomain.com in my browser it takes me to my codeigniter directory.  However how can I make apache take me to my wordpress directory when I go to mydomain.com/blog?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Simple, add an Alias and another directory block *inside* your `VirtualHost` block:

```
Alias /blog/ "/var/www/wordpress/"
<Directory "/var/www/wordpress/">
    ... whatever you want ...
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thanks this works. However if I go to something like mydomain.com/blog/article-1 it takes me back to the codeigniter directory again.  Do you know how to stop this?

Comment: AliasMatch ^/blog/(*) /html/file.php